# LWC: Reactive Properties and expandos

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm reading the [LWC Developer Guider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_reactive_data_types) and I have found this sentence:

> Note Fields are reactive. **Expandos are not reactive**.

I am not able to understand what it means with "**expandos**".
Can you help me or provide some examples of that?

Thanks!

Update: thanks to your help now is clear what expando means but now there is another doubt.

If I have this code:

```
**app.html**
<template>
    <p>object prop: {x.a}</p>

    <button onclick={init}>Init</button>
    <button onclick={update}>Update</button>
</template>

**app.js**
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track x = {};

    init() {
        this.x.a = "a";
    }

    update() {
        this.x.a = "aa";
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, the property "**x.a**" is an expando property since I added it after I defined/created the Object but when I click the two buttons the value on the UI is updated and this means the property is reactive.

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506005/javascript-expando-objects) might be helpful.

Comment: Spring 20 made some changes to how track works (basically, everything is tracked now and internal changes to objects and arrays will force a re-render) - do you know which release you are on? (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_track.htm)

Comment: This works perfectly fine on the Playground. Might be documentation issue?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/-gDPanuO/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have properties of a tracked object trackable themselves and this has been working for us since Summer '19 at least. You do this is in the declaration of the tracked property. For you, you would update the declaration thus:

```
@track x: {
    a: undefined
};
```

This ensures that a change to "x" itself, **or** to the "a" property within it will both invoke reactive processing.

As mentioned by BritishBoyInDC there have been some [recent changes on tracking](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_track.htm) which may be why you see what you see and the apparent divergence against the documentation.